# Succesion of numbers passed into a label coming up with weird results

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 buttons that each have a tag number that I pass into this string in which I am just trying to type in either 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 or 2,2,2,2,2,2,2 or shoot - even, 1,2,2,1,1,1.

Everything works fine until the 8th or 9th time of pressing the button "1" the label says, 111111112.  Then if I press the 1 again the label says, 111111168.

Maybe I am going about this totally wrong? Made sense in my head - but now I am just confused. Any help would be amazing, thank you!

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {

    currentNumber=currentNumber * 10 + (float)[sender tag];

    NSLog(@"currentNumber: %.f", currentNumber);

    phoneNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",currentNumber];

}
```

This image shows me hitting the 1 a bunch of times.. you'd think it would just keep showing 1's all the way across, no?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is a string operation, you should not do it using numbers. Possible reasons of the error: running out of range (because `float` is not big enough), loss of precision (because of the nature of `float`), etc. What you should do instead is

```
phoneNumberLabel.text = [phoneNumberLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]];
```

Comment: +1 for using strings. I was so busy finding the exact precision of floating point numbers that I did not think of the obvious solution!

Comment: @MartinR Yap, this is quite an XY problem... If it's a strings task, then don't use numbers for solving it. (Also, using `int`s cast to `float`s is just so terribly ugly that I almost couldn't resist vomitting on my keyboard.)

Comment: You are right, and a closer look at the screen shot reveals that the number is some phone number, so strings are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

(Single precision) floating point numbers use 23 bits for the mantissa, therefore the largest integer that can be represented exactly by a `float` is 2^24 = 16777216.

All larger integers can not be represented exactly by a `float`, therefore the calculation with numbers having 8 or more digits using `float` cannot be exact.

Double precision floating point numbers can represent numbers up to 2^53 = 9007199254740992 exactly.

A better solution might be to work with integer types (e.g. `uint64_t`), or with strings as suggested in H2CO3's answer.